# Force Footer to Stay at Bottom of Page With Small Viewport

Tags: html, css, electron

I am making an app for myself with ElectronJS. I have managed to get the footer to stay at the bottom of the viewport when it is large, but when I shrink the viewport the footer overlaps some of the content on my page. Can someone please help me? I have attached some pictures to show you all with what I am dealing with.

What I want.[image: Large Viewport]

What I am getting with small viewport.

[image: Small Viewport]

Here is my CSS for my footer class that I am using:

```
/* Footer Styling */
.footer {
    position: absolute; bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove `position: absolute`  and let user see the footer section when scrolled down. Or show us the HTML code to know the actual structure.

Answer (score 0):

if you want client see footer all the time in small viewport use `position: fixed`,
and if you want footer only at the end of all contents in small view port use `@media` in css like this:

```
@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 768px){
    .footer {
       position: relative; 
       /*bottom: 0px;*/
       width: 100%;
       }
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
        .footer {
           position: fixed; 
           bottom: 0;
           left: 0;
           height: 200px;
           width: 100%;
           }
}
```

also if you want use `position: absolute` check height of `.footer` in inspect and add `height: "num"px;` or use `height: 100%`.

you can use `min-height and max-height` in `@media` like this:

```
.footer {
                   position: fixed; 
                   bottom: 0;
                   left: 0;
                   height: 200px;
                   width: 100%;
                   }
@media (min-height: 650px){
        .footer {
           position: relative; 
           /*bottom: 0px;*/
           width: 100%;
           }
    }
```